# Kotlin: Delegate to multiple interfaces with same implementation

Tags: kotlin, interface, delegates

### Situation/Problem

I would like to extend a library via kotlin with nice delegation features, but I got stuck at a place where I want to delegate two different interfaces to the same impl. The problem is, that these two interfaces have common methods (one extends the other).

#### Library I cannot change

So there is a `Base` interface that is extended by both `ExtendedBase` and `Foo1` interfaces. And a `Foo1Impl` that implements `Foo` and `ExtendedBase`, actually there are a lot of implementations and interfaces like that in the library.

```kotlin
interface Base: {
  fun doBase()
  fun doBase2()
  // .. lots of methods
  fun doBaseN()
}

interface ExtendedBase: Base {
  fun doExtended()
  fun doExtended2()
  // .. lots of methods
  fun doExtendedN()
}

interface Foo1: Base {
  fun doFoo1()
}

class Foo1Impl: Foo1, ExtendedBase {
  // some impl for doBase, doExtended and doFoo1
}

interface Foo2: Base {
  fun doFoo2()
}

class Foo2Impl: Foo2, ExtendedBase {
  // ...
}

// ... lots of interfaces and impls

interface FooN: Base {
  fun doFooN()
}

class FooNImpl: FooN, ExtendedBase {
  // ...
}
```

#### Extension of that library (This is what I would like to Do)

I want to extend this library and create my own interfaces that extend the functionality of something that is `ExtendedBase` and `Foo[1..N]`:

```kotlin
interface FooBar1: Foo1 {
  fun doFooBar1()
}

class FooBar1Impl<T>
    constructor(impl: T): FooBar1, ExtendedBase by impl, Foo1 by impl
        where T: Foo1, T: ExtendedBase
{

    override fun doFooBar1() {
        println("foobar1")
    }
}

//.. a lot of other extensions like FooBar[2..N] that all extended the bases with the same logic
```

These extensions would complain about `inheriting multiple implementations of it` because both `Foo1` and `ExtendedBase` extend `Base`. But actually it would be easily decidable because there is only one implementation to delegate to: `impl: T`.

### Things I thought about which do/did not work

**1. Syntax for multi-interface-implementation (not existing in kotlin)**

If there would be a syntax for multi-interface implementations, it might be possible like so:

```kotlin
class FooBar1Impl<T>
    constructor(impl: T): FooBar1, (ExtendedBase, Foo1) by impl
        where T: Foo1, T: ExtendedBase
{ /* ... */ }
```

**2. Inheritance of typeparameter declarations (not possible for jvm)**

If it would be possible for the jvm one could write something like this, but it is not:

```kotlin
class FooBar1Impl<T>
    constructor(impl: T): FooBar1, T by impl
        where T: Foo1, T: ExtendedBase
{ /* ... */ }
```

**3. Nearly possible: base-object that can be extended (still problematic)**

```kotlin
open class BaseExtension constructor(impl: Base) : Base by impl

@Suppress("DELEGATED_MEMBER_HIDES_SUPERTYPE_OVERRIDE")
class FooBar1Impl<T>
    constructor(impl: T): BaseExtension(impl), FooBar1
        where T: Base, T: ExtendedBase
```

But here you can see the suppressed warning is the problem.

**4. Syntax for deciding the default impl (not existing in kotlin)**

```kotlin
class FooBar1Impl<T>
    constructor(impl: T): FooBar1, [default] ExtendedBase by impl, Foo1 by impl
        where T: Foo1, T: ExtendedBase { /* .. */ }
```

### Question

**Is there any workflow that saves me from overriding all `Base` methods by hand? Or any other solution that makes this kind of extension even possible?**

Imagine `Base` has like `100` methods that I would need to manually override.

Answer (score 1):

**Ok I think I might have figured out a solution for now:**

At first I will create a base extension class structure, which delegates methods from both: `Base` and `BaseExtension` to the same constructor-property. I need/want to suppress a warning for this...

*The warning is there because kotlin cannot see that the superclass methods are all delegated to the same implementation `impl` that this implementation delegates the overriding methods to* :

```kotlin
open class BaseExtension<in T: Base>
    constructor(private val impl: T) : Base by impl

@Suppress("DELEGATED_MEMBER_HIDES_SUPERTYPE_OVERRIDE")
open class Extension<in T>
    constructor(private val impl: T) : BaseExtension<T>(impl), ExtendedBase by impl
        where T: Base, T: ExtendedBase {
}
```

Then for every explicit extension I will subclass this `Extension` and implement the explicitly extended interfaces like so:

```kotlin
interface FooBar1: Foo1 {
    fun doFooBar1()
}

@Suppress("DELEGATED_MEMBER_HIDES_SUPERTYPE_OVERRIDE")
class FooBar1Impl<in T>
constructor(private val impl: T) : FooBar1, Extension<T>(impl), Foo1 by impl
    where T: Base, T: ExtendedBase, T: Foo1
{
    fun doFooBar() { /* .. */ }
}
```

In the end this is not a very concise solution, but at least there are no errors and I do not have to implement any already implemented method again. The *warning* though still bugs me, but I cannot see any way around that.

---

**If there is anybody with a solution that does not include these warnings that need to be suppressed, it would be great.**